# what is the PNP Power shell command equivalent to "New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldUserValue"

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

Inside SharePoint 2013 i use this command to get the username of the Created By field:-

```
$Approver = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldUserValue($sourceweb,$ApprovalListItem["Created By"])
```

But in SharePoint online what is the equivalent command in PnP Power-Shell script?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Per my test, you can try following script to retrieve username of Created By field

```
#Parameters
$SiteURL = "https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxx"
$ListName = "TestList"
 
#Connect to Source Site
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL 
 
$ListItems = Get-PnPListItem -List $ListName -PageSize 500 | Where {$_["FileLeafRef"] -like "*.*"}
     
foreach($ListItem in $ListItems){  
     Write-Host "Title:" $ListItem["Title"]
     Write-Host "Author:" $ListItem["Author"].LookupValue
}
```